# Android: Google maps not displaying in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am following an online course to create an Uber clone. However, I am having an issue. From the emulator, when the rider option is clicked, I want to redirect to a new activity called "RiderActivity" and a map is supposed to be shown. However, nothing happens.

Here is my code for the new activity:

```
public class RiderActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(requestCode == 1){
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                updateMap(lastKnownLocation);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void updateMap(Location location){
    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    mMap.clear();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rider);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //setup location manager and listerner
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) ;

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           updateMap(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };


    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    } else{
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }else{
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            updateMap(lastKnownLocation);
        }
    }


    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
   // LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
   // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

While in the MainActivity, I have a method

```
public void redirectActivity(){
if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("riderOrDriver") == "rider"){
  Intent intent =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RiderActivity.class);
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

emulators do not support google maps, until just now, you need to download new emulators with play store support. 
If you have done the above, you might wanna crosscheck your google map api key and check whether you have enabled maps api in developer api console.
Getting a map in app is rather a very simple step by step process as given in google map integration docs.